# Shield UI grid date : how to format

Tags: mysql, gridview, grid, date-formatting, shieldui

I have a Shield UI editable grid with data from a MySql database.  One of the fields/columns is a date. **I cannot figure out how to format the date.**

I have this as part of the columns:

{field: "DATE", title: "Date", format: "{0:/dd/yyyy}")

Changing the format has no effect.

I have tried getting the date from mysql in epoch time as well as standard mysql format of yyyy-mm-dd.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind.  I was pulling in the wrong shield ui files.